# Error while trying to use IF statement in a MySQL FUnction

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to create a MySQL Function and is getting me an error while trying to create it. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I read that this could be because I didn't add "END IF", but i'm doing it. Does it has something to do with the "RETURN 1"?

This is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION esParaCierreSTE(cola VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Corporativo - DISEÑO CORPORATIVO FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE PLANO DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE HATCH)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Edificios - DISEÑO EDIFICIOS FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE PLANO DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE EDIFICIOS)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Instalaciones - DISEÑO INSTALACIONES FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE PLANO DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE INSTALACIONES)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Zona Fuera de Nodo - DISEÑO ZONA NO HABILITADA FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE ZONA NO HABILITADA)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Tickets para Cierre (Fin de reforma)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;

        RETURN 0;
END;
```

This is the error, by the way:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 5

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good so you probably have an issue with delimiters preventing to properly compile the function.

When creating PROCEDUREs or FUNCTIONs you have to change the default delimiter "`;`" so the compiler knows the difference between the delimiters in the function and the end of the CREATE statement itself.

And once its done, you set the default delimiter back.

Which gives :

```
 delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION esParaCierreSTE(cola VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Corporativo - DISEÑO CORPORATIVO FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE PLANO DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE HATCH)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Edificios - DISEÑO EDIFICIOS FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE PLANO DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE EDIFICIOS)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Instalaciones - DISEÑO INSTALACIONES FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE PLANO DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE INSTALACIONES)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Zona Fuera de Nodo - DISEÑO ZONA NO HABILITADA FIN DE REFORMA DE RED (ACTUALIZACIÓN DE TODAS LAS REFORMAS DE ZONA NO HABILITADA)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;
        IF cola like "Diseño red - Tickets para Cierre (Fin de reforma)%" THEN
            RETURN 1;
        END IF;

        RETURN 0;
END //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you! It was that :) I'll keep that in mind, is my first time using functions in MySQL

Comment: and you coded it without error so this is a nice start ;)